# Raycast и нахождение выходного попадания по коллайдеру

Tags: unity3d

Вся физика в 2D. 
Есть `PolygonCollider2D`. Я стреляю по нему лучем:

`RaycastHit2D[] res = new RaycastHit2D[2];`
`var count = Physics2D.Raycast(centerPos, walker.Position - centerPos, rHitFilter, res, distance);`

Вроде бы все работает как положено. НО мне нужно найти не только точку попадания луча в коллайдер, но и точку выхода из него:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли это сделать стандартными методами Unity? Желательно, не придумывая костылей типа: вычислить координаты точки где-то там за коллайдером, лежащую на этой же прямой, и стрельнуть в обратную сторону.